# Fourier Interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation, signal-processing

I have this Equation, that I modeled from my measurements and simulations. $I^{exp}_{l,m} = (\mathbf{F}^{H}.\mathbf{A}.I^{true})_{l,m}$; $H$ is the Hermitian transpose and $\mathbf{F}^{H}$ is a block diagonal inverse Fourier transform operator. $I^{exp}_{l,m}$ and $I^{true}_{l,m}$  are the expected and real images of size  $N_{pix}\times N_{pix}$ pixels. $\mathbf{A}_{}$ is a complex matrix expressed as follows:

$\mathbf{A}_{}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{C}_{01,(t,\nu)}\cdot \mathbf{W}_{01,(t,\nu)}\cdot \mathbf{S}_{01,(t,\nu)} 
\cdot\mathbf{G}\\
    \vdots\\
    \mathbf{C}_{ik,(t,\nu)}\cdot \mathbf{W}_{ik,(t,\nu)}\cdot \mathbf{S}_{ik,(t,\nu)}
\cdot\mathbf{G}\\
    \vdots \\
    \mathbf{C}_{jl,(t,\nu)}\cdot \mathbf{W}_{jl,(t,\nu)}\cdot \mathbf{S}_{jl,(t,\nu)}^{n} 
\cdot\mathbf{G}\\
  \end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf{F}^{H}$ and $\mathbf{A}_{}$ are of shape $(N_{v})\times(N_{pix}N_{pix})$ and $(N_v)\times (N_{pix}N_{pix})$  respectively. Please ignore the elements in $\mathbf{A}_{}$ but consider the shape. This equation model data compression and imaging (in interferometry synthesis imaging). From my model, $I^{true}_{l,m}$ and $\mathbf{A}_{}$ are known. What is the best approach to use to compute  $I^{exp}_{l,m}$? Is there any Python tools for this Fourier interpolation?

Comment: Not sure how you want a DFT to be non-symmetric. $F$ should be a symmetric matrix. If it's a 'truncated' version of the DFT, then you may want to consider instead using full DFT and then throwing away the unneeded values, since this allows for `fft` to be used.

Comment: Python must have an FFT implementation that allows you take the 1-D FFT of a 2-D array along a given dimension. So you can either multiply $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{I^{\mathrm{true}}}$ and then take the FFT of the columns, or take the FFT of the columns of $\mathbf{A}$ and then multiply the result by $\mathbf{I^{\mathrm{true}}}$.

Comment: Thank you $\@$AlexR and $\@$AnonSubmitter85, from your answers I got a lot of ideas and errors from the Equation.